# Tee command not appending

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to write a bash script named updateFile.sh. It's currently as follows:

```
function insertIntoFile(){
    local variable=$1
    local target=$2
    echo "${variable}" | tee -a "${target}";
}

insertIntoFile "export/ foo=bar" "~/.bash_profile"
```

Running `bash -x ./updateFile.sh`

For output, I get...

```
...
+ echo 'export/ foo=bar'
+ tee -a '~/.bash_profile'
export/ foo=bar
```

however, when I `cat ~/.bash_profile`

It's still empty of the given string.

I've tried the export without the slash, so I know that's not it, and I've dug through stack overflow, and everything I've seen seems to indicate that this should work, yet I don't see why it's not or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) commented, your use of tilde inside double quotes:

```
insertIntoFile "export/ foo=bar" "~/.bash_profile"
```

suffers from the surprise of `~` not being expanded inside double quotes. Use the `$HOME` variable or remove the double quotes:

```
insertIntoFile "export/ foo=bar" "$HOME/.bash_profile"
```

or

```
insertIntoFile "export/ foo=bar" ~/.bash_profile
```

I would additionally recommend the use of `printf` over `echo`, since various implementations of `echo` might attempt to parse (read: mangle) a "$variable" value that starts with `-n` or `-e`. Change this line:

```
echo "${variable}" | tee -a "${target}";
```

to this:

```
printf '%s\n' "${variable}" | tee -a "${target}";
```